# OBSOLETE - Build an app with Soapi.JS and gain praise and adulation. And some rep

Tags: discussion, obsolete, libraries

### Bounty Contest:

Build anything using the [Soapi.JS](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-easy-to-use-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api) JavaScript wrapper and either post the code or a link to a live demo.

When the question gets old enough (7 days I think) I will click 'start a bounty' and offer up 300 points. Add the 50 bonus points that the site tacks on and the answer with the most votes when the bounty expires picks up a cool **350** rep and a link from http://soapi.info.

Use whatever tools and libraries float your boat, jquery, mootools, dojo etc, but interaction with the API must be driven by [Soapi.JS](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-easy-to-use-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api).

Good luck and may the most ridiculous app win. ;-)

**NOTE** Time allowing, I will be happy to answer *any* questions about the library and help out with code if you get stuck. Simply post an answer describing your problem and any relevant code.

Comment: I was planning on playing with the soapi.js library in the next few days anyway, so this is some added incentive ;)

Comment: Sounds like a challenge to me! I will begin planning something.

Comment: @smark - no worries dude. Now I see. I am going to delete my FRIST! that makes me look like a complete idiot now. thanks for the heads up, we can delete these comments if you like... unless you want to look like you are talking to your self ;p

Comment: @george, 53346 is a question, I can only assume that you are looking for answer your answer - try 53466. http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm is a good tool for building queries and examining the expected results.

Comment: @george - something to consider: http://stackapps.com/questions/707/api-help-suggestion-answers-id-summary-incorrect . r.e. your last question, soapi is a complete and faithful rendering of the so api. If the api exposes a method to do what you are asking then soapi provides a route and parameters to do the same. when in doubt use soapi-explore.

Comment: @George - start an answer and describe what you are trying to do and how you are getting stuck. and please delete all the support comments. comments are not a good place for support dialog as the 'comment' comments get buried.

Comment: @code: Deleted the comments now.

Comment: please don't tag things [library] unless they are actually library entries. This is a contest of some sort.

Comment: @code: Congrats on the "Most Entries" prize - you deserved it!

Comment: @geo - same to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog) is my entry. It basically allows you to embed the open-source ads from Meta in your blog, etc.

It is simply a .js file you can include on the page.

---

**My evaluation:** Soapi.js is a *very* intuitive library for JavaScript. And by that, I mean the methods are laid out in a way that you would expect them to be. The whole thing is relatively self-documenting and integrates well with my above-mentioned application. I especially like the fact that API changes don't require a huge code rewrite - only a quick download!

Comment: not that you have much competition but you should probably link to this answer from your announcement and beg for votes here as that will determine who picks up the check when the bounty expires. (I will not click check unless there are not enough votes (3 i think) for the site to pick the winner)

Comment: @code: **Don't let the site pick!** If you do, only half the bounty gets awarded. You will just have to pick it yourself.

Comment: ahhh, i did not consider that. looks like i have to pick. good catch

Comment: no worries. i will cut the check @ 0:0:0 mountain time.

Comment: @geo - if you add a brief *honest* evaluation of soapi.js to this answer i will break all the rules and cut the check early! ;-)

Comment: @code: Sorry, got to this late - I'll write one now. **Update:** There, wrote one.

Comment: @code: In addition, did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html) page that I also made with Soapi.js? Vote for it [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/796/stackad-scroller).

Comment: ding ding ding, winna winna big chicken dinna! for the record, now that the heated contest is concluded, this is exactly what I was looking for, a short sweet app written in a matter of hours leveraging  the library. thanks for playing geo. r.e. votes-done and done.

Comment: @code: Ya, he's right.

Comment: @smark et.al hmmm, guess i need to pull myself away from apps and visit meta every once in a while. thanks

Comment: @code: Actually it was on the blog :)

Comment: @code: Uhm... according to the question above, I get a mention on Soapi.info?

Comment: i have not had a chance to push changes to the site. i have to sleep *sometime*. it is coming in tonight's push.

Comment: @Geo - your soapi apps are linked from soapi.info. thanks for participating and good work.

Comment: @code: No problem. Thanks for keeping up to date with the new API version number changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write this as a comment, but it got too long:

I've got about 50% of the way through my JS app using your wrapper, but I'm heading back to work after some extended leave and there's no way I'm going to get it finished. That said, what I used worked great, only one suggestion, it would be great if the requests could be synchronous (rather than a-sync), because then when queuing up multiple requests to the same method you don't need to create a watcher.

E.G. I wanted to retrieve 5 individual questions, mixing and matching them from different sites. So:

```
for (var x=0;x<sitedata.length;x++){
    var soapi = new  Soapi.RouteFactory(sitedata[x][0], apiKey);
    var q = soapi.QuestionsById(sitedata[x][1]);
    q.getResponse(function success(data) {
         //.....
    })
}
```

then needs a `setInterval` to detect when all the responses have come back (increasing a progress meter along the way). Not a huge thing, probably won't upset too many people, but I found myself constantly creating watchers to then fire another function.

Apart from that, I applaud a job well done and I look forward to your 30" monitor winning application (although in my opinion you'll be hard pressed to beat [Six to Eight](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client) - if it gets released before the cutoff date).

Comment: Hey, the rest of us haven't given up on the monitor either :)

Comment: Aside from the obvious dark pit of hades into which I would be thrown if I were able to implement a blocking call in JS, how to implement a blocking call in a jsonp wrapper is not immediately apparent to me. The api calls are made via jsonp, injected script tags, not XMLHttpRequest. Do you have any ideas?  I have implemented a viable blocking call in the silverlight version, but then I have threads and am able to force the call to be made on a thread other than the UI thread. No such animal in regards to browsers (workers in chrome) in general distribution any time in the near future.

Comment: And I typically chain calls that would otherwise be suited to be run synchronously. e.g. make the next call from within the success function. With a little imagination and a flag or two this can serve such a purpose. And as far as a queue goes, I have an implementation somewhere in my qunit code. I will try to dig it up.

Comment: Writing a blocking jsonp call seems like it shouldn't even be possible :)

Comment: @code, as usual everything you've said sounds right... I was just too late into the design of my application to change it to one of the methods you mentioned. I didn't really put much thought into the idea to be honest, but I can see the problem that this is faced. I guess the answer is "no - next time design your app to use the library properly" ;)

Comment: Can someone -1 this just so that it sits at the bottom of the list and doesn't get the bounty

Answer (score 1):

<strike>**This will eventually turn into the entry for my app.**</strike> *It didn't! See my other answer.*

*Support: the page at http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/ is having some trouble pulling answers.*

```
// an url built with soapi-explore...

// http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/53346/answers?body=true&min=6&order=asc&sort=votes

// can be easily translated to Soapi.JS..

new Soapi.RouteFactory('api.meta.stackoverflow.com', '')
.QuestionsByIdAnswers(53346).applyParameters({
    body: true,
    min: 6,
    order: 'asc',
    sort: 'votes'
}).getResponse(
function success(data) {
    alert(data.answers[0].score);
},
function error(err) {
    alert(err.message);
});
```

Comment: george, i already addressed this - you are trying to query an 'answer' source with a question id. try 53466, which is an answer id to see what I mean. AnswersById gets answers specifically requested.  If you want all of the answers to a specific question, use QuestionsById or QuestionsByIdAnswers

Comment: and to answer your other question, yes, the api supports (but does not properly document) the ability to all of the answers for a specific question with a score of 6 or higher.  Here is the raw url, http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/53346/answers?body=true&min=6&order=asc&sort=votes I will leave it to you to translate that into soapi.JS. (hint, the soapi was generated directly from the api)

Comment: And did I mention that I spend a LOT of time in soapi-explore. You don't use visual studio so soapi-explore can save you a lot of time with the parameter tooltip documentation. you can build requests and test them, see the results, and then very easily translate the url in to soapi.JS

Comment: @code: I **changed** my code to *QuestionsByIdAnswers* already. It **still** doesn't work.

Comment: And I am having trouble translating API calls to SOAPI calls, though I'm starting to get the hang of it now.

Comment: @george - this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @code: This? What is "this?"

Comment: what? you want me to write your code and then post it in comments? ;-) work with me dude.

Comment: @code: Of course not, it's just that I have no idea where the problem even *is* - once we can find it, I can probably fix it no problem.

Comment: **Never mind.** I didn't see that you edited my answer :)

Comment: @code: I have copied your code verbatim and I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'apiVersion' of undefined.
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'QuestionsByIdAnswers'

Comment: @george - the api had some drama last night. check http://twitter.com/soapiwatch and http://twitter.com/soapigen and then download new js files from http://soapi.info/Services/CodeGeneration.aspx - I suggest that if you want to write code against an evolving beta api that you take advantage of the notification and discovery tools i have provided on http://soapi.info.  You gotta keep up, dude. ;-)

Comment: Also - you will probably the reason you cannot find `apiVersion` on stats is that there is no member of that name. try `api_version`. Ok? If you have questions about a member of the api in it's running state look @ http://soapi.info/Services/Watch.aspx and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: And whatever you copied likely wasn't mine. or wasn't copied verbatim.

Comment: @code: I know. My mobile client went crazy last night too and I had a feeling in the back of my mind that that's why your code wasn't working either. As for copying code, I just copied and pasted what you edited into my question above. Well, I'll get the new versions of the files and see what I can do.

Comment: @code: Okay. I just updated the 'Soapi.Generated.js' file to the latest version on your site. Still have the same problems :(

Comment: I just clicked on the url in your answer, http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/ , and I get an alert of '9' - seems to be working. and disregard my snide remark about apiVersion above, I misread the comment. I don't know why you are not getting a valid instance of RouteFactory but your online example is working just fine. Use it as a point of reference.

Comment: @code: Don't worry about it :) I guess the problem is with Google Chrome on Linux (my browser). Let me try it in Firefox. **Edit:** Yup, it works :P *I wonder why it doesn't work in Chrome...*

Comment: @works in chrome on windows. sounds like the soapi.generated.js code is not being executed properly. it builds the routemaps at runtime from metadata. I will fire up my linux test farm later tonight and give it a once over.

Comment: @code: Sorry for all of the trouble. Guess it was my browser all this time :) Hopefully you can figure out what the problem is quickly. I'll work with Firefox in the meantime.

Comment: @code: Hey! Guess what - when I include the jQuery library directly before Soapi.js, it works in Chrome! Weird.

Comment: yeah, that is weird. i consciously write unobtrusive code. there should be NO conflicts with jquery. in any case, that tidbit will be added as a troubleshooting note in the documentation when it gets generated.

Comment: @code: I think I'm going to start a new answer for my app now :) These comments would detract from it anyway.