# OBSOLETE - StackAd - An Easy Way to Display Open-Source Ads on Your Site/Blog

Tags: app, javascript, obsolete, soapi.js

> ### Note:
>
> This page is due for an update but until then you can add StackAd to your site by adding:
>
> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'
>         src='http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/stackad.min.js'>
> </script>
> ```
>
> to the `<head>` section of your page and sticking the following `<div>` on the page where you want the ads to appear:
>
> ```
> <div class='stackad' data-site='stackoverflow.com'></div>
> ```
>
> ...where `data-site` is the *parent* site of the Stack Exchange site whose ads you want to display.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
StackAd demo available [here](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/test.html).

### About

StackAd pulls the answers from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010) question that have 6 or more upvotes and displays a random ad in the box. The code is provided as a .js file you can embed in your pages. The instructions are [here](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/).

#### License

As is common with all of my open-source apps, I am going with the MIT license.

#### Download

http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/stackad.js <- This file can be hotlinked and has been minified to save bandwidth
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/stackad-source.js <- This is the source
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/test.html <- to see a demo
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html <- to see an even better demo

#### Platform

The code should work with any JavaScript enabled browser.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

The code is written in JavaScript and uses the [Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-easy-to-use-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api) wrapper for interfacing with the API.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty unique use for the API! <s>But... what are you going to do when a new thread is created and the question number changes?</s> - nevermind, if you do a copy/paste style app then you can change your hotlinked JS file.

Comment: @Farseeker: Ya, that's basically the idea :)

Comment: I like it. Short, Sweet, Scooby Snack of an app.

Comment: Please also vote for this app [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/666/bounty-build-an-app-with-soapi-js-and-gain-praise-and-adulation-and-some-rep/742#742) so I can win the mini-contest.

Comment: You can now link to [stackad.js](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/stackad.js)!

Comment: Please let me know when you use it on your blog/site. I really appreciate feedback!

Comment: As a complete side-note, consider supporting another open-source project by voting for [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/53466#53466).

Comment: @George, just looking at `stackad.js`, a few suggestions: 1) Check for JQuery and include it's not there (hotlink to the Google Hosted version), 2) Check for SOAPI.js and include it automatically if it's not there. 3) The ID of "banner" is incredibly common. Maybe call it "so-oss-banner" or something? This way it's an all-in-one solution and is really just a copy/paste solution. Also, 4) for your own bandwidths sake, you might want to run it through a minifier. That copyright notice will cost you a lot of money if you're not careful Other than that, looking good!

Comment: @Farseeker: Ya, those pretty much mirror my todo list - I will fix those pretty quickly. #2 might be slightly more difficult though. **Update:** Fixed #3 already.

Comment: @code: Do you mind if we hotlink `Soapi.js` and `Soapi.Generated.js`?

Comment: I have created a minified version suitable for hotlinking.

Comment: well, the files will be in the same place but until the api goes gold and stops moving I can guarantee the functionality. This would be the issue with hotlinking. And I have yet to wire up minification to my build process yet. when I find myself with some time I will build in minification and output files with version numbers that can be linked.

Comment: @Farseeker: I implemented your idea - the script now searches for and detects if jQuery has been included and otherwise loads it from Google.

Comment: @code: In the meantime? Ah, never mind. I'll just host them on mine until you get something set up.

Comment: I have minified the Soapi files and they are automatically included with the stackad.js source when necessary.

Comment: Looking good :)

Comment: geo - when the api froze, i suspended code generation and began refactoring and polishing soapi.js. i am about to push the much refactored and streamlined soapi.js, so if you are linking you will want to get a local copy as a lot of the redundancy and other artifacts that are common in code generation have been removed and a few typenames have changed. Nothing outwardly drastic, but a much better library has emerged. upgrading your apps should be a piece of cake. I will be pushing @ midnight. heads up.

Comment: This demo no longer appears to function.  Closing...

Comment: @Kevin: Whoooah... I need a chance to fix it! There. Fixed.

Comment: Reopened, as it works now.

Comment: geo - help a brother out, wouldja?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/60263#60263

Comment: @code: Smart looking ad! +1

Comment: @code: Can you consider voting for [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/60473#60473) one, please?

Comment: geo - the copyright is missing your name.

Comment: @Sky: Sorry, which copyright?

Comment: I am relatively new to this site and open-source-Advertising. I love open source and admire the concept. Can you please tell me if it is legal / acceptable to put these open source ads in my blog I am building? I have put up the ad related code in [my blog](http://java-automation.blogspot.in/p/environment-setup.html)

Comment: @MonkeyInstincts: I'm not a lawyer, but I certainly don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Hi George thanks for a quick turn around. I can't see the ads loading now for me. It was wroking fine few hours back. I see below error message in Console logs of Google Chrome & Firefox browsers. *GET http://api.meta.undefined/1.1/questions?tagged=community-ads&sort=creation&jsonp=jsonp_callback_0&key=bLgPLydVUkSNtkp6LNPwNw  stackad.min.js:1*

Comment: @MonkeyInstincts: Ah, sorry for the confusion. You're using an older version of StackAd. The latest version (and instructions for using it) are listed at the very top of this question (in the light-grey box).

Comment: Thank you for clarification George. I have the ads up and running now. I love the concept. I don't have enough reputation to +1 the post.

Comment: Links and subdomain are (long) dead.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way for this work for other, non-stackoverflow (think: [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011)) community ads?

Comment: You know... I honestly never thought of that... I will investigate this and report my findings.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison shouldn't be too hard, it's already pulling it from a stackoverflow question...

Comment: It is, but some bugs were later discovered in the StackAd code that need to be fixed as well.

Comment: I totally forgot about this - but yeah - this has been implemented now.