# CoreStack : An Objective C Library

Tags: library, objective-c

#### About

An Objective C 2.0 wrapper around the Stack Exchange API. Powers [Six to Eight](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client). Carefully woven threads for easy creation of non-blocking UIs, and full serialisation support for easy state persistence. In short, what was needed to create a well behaved iPhone application.

I've included a small README.txt, but documentation is otherwise sparse. As time permits over the next week, I'll be writing a few blog posts on the creation of Six to Eight, and the use of the API (along with coding against the SE API in general).

#### License

MIT Licence. Basically, do whatever you like. Just don't judge me too harshly when you find problems.

#### Download

Linked from http://sixtoeightapp.com/open_source.php, or just visit the github directly at http://github.com/archgrove/CoreStack

#### Platform

Objective C 2.0 platforms. Basically, that's Mac OS X Leopard, or iOS.

### Contact

Bug reports, comments, patches and abuse to adamw at archgrove.co.uk.

### Code

Pure Objective C, but with the help of [ghunit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/) (Gabriel Handford) and [JSON API](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) (Stig Brautaset).

### Examples

In case it helps, I just uploaded one of the UIViewControllers from SixToEight to http://sixtoeightapp.com/code/SiteStatisticsView.m ([and h](http://sixtoeightapp.com/code/SiteStatisticsView.h)). It shows the basic usage the API was designed for - given a CSSite, it demos getting request parameters, making requests, receiving answers and serialising results. I'll add some more interesting ones later in the week when I've check them over for obvious bad examples.

Comment: How exactly do you define a CSSite? using the SiteStatistics example, initWithSite:@"StackOverflow", doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You need to build a `CSSite` object via `- (id)initWithDescriptor:(CSSiteDescriptor*)_descriptor;`. To build a site descriptor, either use `CSSiteDescriptor`s `(id)initWithName:(NSString*)_name andEndPoint:(NSString*)_api_endpoint;`, or use `CSAuth`, calling `updateSites` then using the `sites` property (which is an object vector of the `CSSiteDescriptors` provided by StackAuth) once your delegate is notified that the site list is available.